# Angular http post request appending parenthesis unexpectedly

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, angular6

When a request is made. i have seen that extra parenthesis are attached before the request type. like below.

```
{"username":"demo","password":"123"}POST /authentication/
```

and my back-end is refusing this with error code 405 method not allowed.

Back-end is in **Django rest_framework** and front end is in **Angular 6**.

I don't know how to rid from these parenthesis. Either i have to look into front end, why it is appending these extra parenthesis or i have to see which middle-ware is stopping this in Django.

Sample request code of angular is below:

```
this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(datum),{'headers':headers}).subscribe()
```

**Edit:**
Error is coming after each logout request. Whenever I am trying to destroy session during logout either it is successful or not from back-end, error start coming right after that.

Comment: the question is not clear please post the code where the object  **datum** is created !

Comment: I have shared the portion where the code is failing. Can I share the whole file here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Don't destroy local storage in a response body of back-end service.

```
this.http.post(this.logout_url, '', {'headers':headers}).subscribe(
  response => {
    localStorage.removeItem('usersession');
    localStorage.clear();
    }
  });
```

Destroy the local storage first to get the user logout and then call the back-end logout service. like below:

```
localStorage.removeItem('usersession');
localStorage.clear();

this.http.post(this.logout_url, '', {'headers':headers}).subscribe();
```